# Health check for Lichee Pi Nano with UART

Tags: uart, arm, linux

I have a Lichee Pi Nano SBC, TTL Adapter (UART) and 8 GB SD-Card.

Following pins connected together:

```
TTL adapter    LicheePi
TXD            TX
RXD            RX
3v3            3v3
GND            GND
```

After this setting I connected USB cable to my PC and run following command. But noting was appeared.

```
# minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Then I tested following setting:

```
TTL adapter    LicheePi
TXD            TX
RXD            RX
```

And connect Micro-USB to board. Then connect a LED to 3v3 and GND pins of board. LED was turned on but nothing appeared on `minicom`.

How can I debug or health check for this board ? I'm new to electronics.

Comment: Did you install an operating system onto the SD card? that is the most common reason why one of these types of boards wouldn't do anything when turned on. If you did install one, did you install it correctly, and is it actually supposed to send something through the UART?

Comment: Connecting TXD output to another TXD output is generally wrong. Double check how the connections should be made.

Comment: @Justme actually it can be either way around since the specification for RS-232 is that TXD on the modem is where the modem receives data which it transmits on the phone line

Comment: @user253751 Sure, but none of the devices is a modem and these are not RS-232 devices either. Of course, an USB adapter or SBC with TXD pin that is an input could exist and can be verified from manuals. What is suspicious is the 3.3V supply pins being connected together. Maybe they should not.

Comment: UARTs are often labeled the same as RS-232, which is designed exclusively for modems. Historical reasons. So TXD may or may not be wired to TXD and you have to check both datasheets to be sure.